# The InterstitialAd is not shown in the App, Logcat says: The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet

Tags: java, android

The App is starting and running normally but the InterstitialAd is not shown.
build.gradles are OK
AndroidManifest sems to be OK
I tried it before with an On Start App Ad it worked with out any probelms, but here it don't work.

I made everything how its in the Video Tutorial was shown:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTY5gKmhqxU&t=4s
Except the FullScreenContentCallback(){ I put in the InterstitialAd.load function.
Otherwise the App crashes.

Any One have an Idea why the InterstitialAd is not showing?
ThankYou

Here my Code:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAdLoadCallback;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

  private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd; //Variable AdMob

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//AdMob
        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {}
        });


        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
//ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712
        InterstitialAd.load(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest,
                new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                        // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
                        // an ad is loaded.
                        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                        //Log.i(TAG, "onAdLoaded");
                        mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback(){
                            @Override
                            public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                                // Called when fullscreen content is dismissed.
                                Log.d("TAG", "The ad was dismissed.");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {
                                // Called when fullscreen content failed to show.
                                Log.d("TAG", "The ad failed to show.");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                                // Called when fullscreen content is shown.
                                // Make sure to set your reference to null so you don't
                                // show it a second time.
                                mInterstitialAd = null;
                                Log.d("TAG", "The ad was shown.");
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        // Handle the error
                        //Log.i(TAG, loadAdError.getMessage());
                        mInterstitialAd = null;
                    }
                });

        if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
            mInterstitialAd.show(MainActivity.this);
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.");
        }
}
```

Mainfest File:

```
<!-- Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>
```

Comment: You are trying to show the Ad right after calling `load` which obviously won't work as the Ad hasn't loaded yet. If you want to show the Ad as soon as it loads then use `show(...)` in `onAdLoaded`.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer now it works

Answer (score 1):

you can show an Ad after it will load successfully, if Ad was not loaded, it can't be shown, so you must load before show Ad.

**Update your code with this.**

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAdLoadCallback;
    
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {
    
                private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd; //Variable AdMob
    
                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //AdMob
                    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
                        }
                    });
    
    
                    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    //ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712
                    InterstitialAd.load(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest,
                            new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                                    // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
                                    // an ad is loaded.
                                    mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                                    //Log.i(TAG, "onAdLoaded");
                                    mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                                            // Called when fullscreen content is dismissed.
                                            Log.d("TAG", "The ad was dismissed.");
                                        }
    
                                        @Override
                                        public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {
                                            // Called when fullscreen content failed to show.
                                            Log.d("TAG", "The ad failed to show.");
                                        }
    
                                        @Override
                                        public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                                            // Called when fullscreen content is shown.
                                            // Make sure to set your reference to null so you don't
                                            // show it a second time.
                                            mInterstitialAd = null;
                                            Log.d("TAG", "The ad was shown.");
                                        }
                                    });
    
                                    if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
                                        mInterstitialAd.show(MainActivity.this);
                                    } else {
                                        Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.");
                                    }
                                }
    
                                @Override
                                public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                                    // Handle the error
                                    //Log.i(TAG, loadAdError.getMessage());
                                    mInterstitialAd = null;
                                }
                            });
    
    
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer now it works